# Cannot open doc file in C: partition with LibreOffice in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mount, libreoffice

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 and Win 10 dual boot. I want to open a doc file on my Windows partition in Ubuntu but cannot. I get an error:

> General input/output error while accessing /media/myfile.doc

I don't understand what the problem is. Can I open my doc file in Ubuntu using LibreOffice?

[image: screenshot of popup error]